# How do I filter this in array?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I do have tags like this

```
search100
web250
seo36
analytics5060
traffic8000
web2.0
```

I want remove numbers from this tag so I can use this code in php

```
preg_replace("/\d+$/gm", "", input)
```

but I want to keep `web2.0` without intact...how do I filter this when I am using a loop..I do have more than 100k tags like this.

Comment: Can you provide more examples of tags you don't want to strip? It's not clear what makes `web2.0` special. Is it the `.` between two numbers? Is it that it has digits before a non-digit character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the pattern `/(\w)\d+$/m` and `$1` as replacement:

```
preg_replace('/(\w)\d+$/m', '$1', $input)
```

This pattern requires that there is at least one word character before the sequence of digits.

And to apply this replacement on each element of an array use [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map):

```
array_map(function($elem) { return preg_replace('/(\w)\d+$/m', '$1', $elem); }, $arr);
```

If you can’t use an [anonymous function](http://php.net/functions.anonymous) (available since PHP 5.3) like in my example, you can either define a separate function, use [`create_function`](http://php.net/create_function) instead or just use a `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

From your vague description and the small sample, it seems you could just use:

```
$input = preg_replace("/\d\d+$/m", "", $input);
```

This would spare the 2.0 suffix, because it looks for two consecutive numbers as minimum. But another way to accomplish it would be a negative lookbehind `(?<!2\.)\d+$`